# Performance comparison between Lucene Vs PyLucene Vs Whoosh

Tags: lucene, whoosh, pylucene

Is there any benchmark comparing Lucene Vs PyLucene Vs Whoosh?

Lucene seems to be far ahead in terms of popularity, but I'm looking for something more Pythonic. So just want to get rough idea on the tradeoff.